# Get the least of a series of numbers WITHOUT an array (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net

Yes, this is part of a homework assignment. And that's the trouble - I know I could use an array, but we haven't reached that part of the class yet, so I'm not supposed to use that yet. The user inputs five numbers (Doubles, using InputBoxes) and the program should drop the lowest value and calculate the average of the remaining four. At this present juncture, we've been studying For...Next loops, and this is the corresponding For...Next section in the book, so I know I'm supposed to incorporate one in here somewhere, but I have yet to figure out how to calculate and then keep a running "lowest" variable.

Thanks for the help!

Original:

```
Sub getAverage()
    Dim first As Double = CDbl(InputBox("Enter the first grade.", "First"))
    Dim second As Double = CDbl(InputBox("Enter the second grade.", "Second"))
    Dim third As Double = CDbl(InputBox("Enter the third grade.", "Third"))
    Dim fourth As Double = CDbl(InputBox("Enter the fourth grade.", "Fourth"))
    Dim fifth As Double = CDbl(InputBox("Enter the fifth grade.", "Fifth"))
    Dim min As Double = 0
    Dim sum As Double = 0
    For count As Integer = 1 To 5

    Next
    Dim average As Double = 0
    txtOutput.Text = average.ToString("N2")

End Sub
```

Edit 1 (Thanks Guffa): What should I compare the current grade to?

```
Sub getAverage()
    Dim min As Double = 0
    Dim sum As Double = 0
    For count As Integer = 1 To 5
        Dim grade As Double = InputBox("Enter Grade #" & count)
        sum += grade
        If grade < '??? Then
          min = grade
        End If
    Next
    Dim average As Double = 0
    txtOutput.Text = average.ToString("N2")

End Sub
```

Comment: even for homework, indeed *especially* so, you need to show some effort and what you have tried.  with no code to start with, it is like a do-this-for-me question

Comment: Cool. How is it now?

Comment: you need to set the min to the larget possible value, then you can say if grade < min then min = grade. You need to do this so the first input is set to min value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have five input statements, put one input statement in the loop instead.

You would need to keep track of:

```
- The sum of all values
- The lowest value that you encounter
```

Just add each numbers to the sum as they are entered, and update the lowest value if the entered value is lower than what you have got before.

When the user has entered all the numbers, you just subtract the lowest number from the sum of all the values, that gives you the same value as if you had added up all the numbers except the lowest one.

The average is just the sum divided by the number of values.

Comment: Thanks! That "what you have got before" part is tripping me up, though. How can I represent something from a previous loop?

Comment: @Francho: You just keep it in a variable. Like the sum that you add to, except that you replace the value if the new value is lower. In the first iteration you always want to use the value, so you can use `If count = 1 Or grade < min Then` for that.